How is Hyperterminal Working, regardless of port settings?
I am trying to connect to a Quectel GNSS device that creates a virtual COM port in windows. I have always assumed these virtual devices work like a standard RS232 port with a fixed baud, however I have observed that when I connect to this port using Hyperterminal, it does not matter what settings I have, the data still streams normally. The baud can be anything, the stop bit can be anything, nothing changes the data stream.
Maybe I have always misunderstood how Hyperterminal works, but how is this device and virtual COM port able to work, regardless of the settings.
I realize this may not be the most appropriate place for this question, however I am shooting in the dark since it could be a protocol question related to EE topics.

It's not about how Hyperterminal works. It's how the virtual COM ports work.
Hyperterm or any other program just opens COM port and sets the baud rate you select and does what you want with it.
But since the data does not really go through an UART but just over USB packets, there is no concept of baud rate or stop bits that applies when communicating with USB devices that look like COM ports.
So this does not relate in any way to TTL or RS-232 or even UARTs.
Virtual COM ports are virtual for this reason. They can be opened and data can be sent and received by programs that want to open COM ports. But in reality the driver that provides a non-physical COM port can do whatever it wants to send or receive data, such as send it over USB or Ethernet or patch it to another virtual COM port so you can have a virtual null modem between two Hyperterms running on same computer.
They just pass bytes, but not through via an actual UART that does have to work at some rate and use some parity and stop bit settings.

Virtual com ports can communicate with real com ports, so minimally, the tx needs to honor baud rate and data width setup.

@ScottSeidman The only case where that is true is an USB UART port. Of course the COM port driver needs to provide the methods to set the baud rate etc of the UART. But none of this is true when the other device is e.g. an USB MCU that just sends and receives data and there is no UART. And in the OPs case there is no UART.

Thanks for the clarification. I suppose this leads to another question - how would one go about communicating with a device like this through programming libraries? It seems like a standard serial port library would no longer apply? Would it need to support USB?

@TJames if your USB device exposes itself as a virtual COM port, then in your software you treat it just like any other COM port - virtual or 'real'. Your software doesn't need to know that it's actually connected over USB.

@TJames That's why it is a virtual COM port. It's a standard COM port for your programs but not really a COM port at all because it's just a more direct data pipe to your whatever device and it just skips the data being actually passing through a physical COM port.

@brhans That's what I have been trying to do, however all serial libraries I have tried require a baud rate, stop bit, etc.. and simply using the default does not allow data to come through, therefor I am very curious how Hyperterminal can accomplish this.

@TJames Of course they are relevant when you open real COM ports. Just use the defaults. I have never had that problem. Maybe it relates to handshaking being virtually required. We can't know what you are trying to do, how, and what's wrong with it. Just test with Python, I have controlled e.g. projectors and TVs and whatnot serial devices regardless of them being USB serial ports or virtual USB serial ports.

@Justme Thanks, I usually have great luck with serial devices and virtual ports, but this one has me baffled. I have tried every major baud rate, every handshaking method, but nothing works. I have also confirmed the code itself using UART converters. I just can't tell how Hyperterminal defaults to something that works..

@TJames Isn't HyperTerm last seen on XP? Are you working on XP? Have you tried any of the other common, free, and open-source terminals if they work and how they do it? But that's beyond electronics.

@Justme Yes, I have tried 3 other serial monitoring applications. None of them show the data stream. Hyperterminal is the only one that does.. ugh

@TJames So you have not used a terminal program which lets you to wiggle the handshake pins to your liking? Which handshake methods you have even tried? Or which method the GNSS device requires?
